# How do I prevent keyboard navigation in an AutoCompleteBox from firing the SelectionChanged event?

Tags: wpf, xaml, autocomplete, wpftoolkit, selectionchanged

I'm trying to build a search field using the `AutoCompleteBox` from the WPF Toolkit. The AutoCompleteBox's Text property is bound to a property in a `ViewModel` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. When the property is changed, it fetches new suggestions to show to the user.

This gets mucked up if the user uses arrow keys to scan through the list of autocomplete suggestions before choosing one - the moment the cursor move into the popup, `SelectionChanged` is fired, the text field gets a new value, and the autocomplete suggestions are re-collected. This also interferes with my desire to use the `SelectionChanged` event to kick off a search.

Is there any way to prevent the SelectionChanged event from firing on keyboard navigation?

Here's how I have things set up. Note `sc:SearchField` is a subclass of `AutoCompleteBox` that only provides a way to access the `TextBox` property on the `AutoCompleteBox` so I can call functions like `SelectAll()`

XAML:

```
<sc:SearchField x:Name="SearchField" DataContext="{Binding SearchBoxVm}" Text="{Binding Query, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding QuerySuggestions, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" IsTextCompletionEnabled="False" Margin="54,10,117,67" Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="14" PreviewKeyUp="searchField_OnKeyup" Foreground="{Binding Foreground, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontStyle="{Binding QueryFont, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
        </sc:SearchField>
```

ViewModel:

```
void GetQuerySuggestions()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Query) && !Query.Equals(DEFAULT_TEXT))
    {
        QueryFont = FontStyles.Normal;
        Foreground = Brushes.Black;
        QuerySuggestions = SearchAssistant.GetQueryRecommendations(_query);
    }
}

public string _query = DEFAULT_TEXT;
public string Query
{
    get
    {
        return _query;
    }
    set
    {
        _query = value;
        GetQuerySuggestions();
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Query");
    }
}

List<string> querySuggestions = new List<string>();
public List<string> QuerySuggestions
{
    get { return querySuggestions; }
    set
    {
        querySuggestions = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("QuerySuggestions");
    }
}
```

SearchField subclass:

```
public class SearchField : AutoCompleteBox
{
    public TextBox TextBox 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return (this.GetTemplateChild("Text") as TextBox);
        } 
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are wanting to do but I have the following code which only changes the selection when the 'Enter' key is pressed or the mouse is used to select an item from the list (left mouse button clicked).  I can arrow up and down the list without issue and only fire the selection changed event when the user presses enter or clicks on the desired entry.

Note that I am using the AutoCompleteBox and not the SearchField as you are using.

In XAML:

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox Name="OmniSearchTextBox"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding CompanyList}" 
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         IsTextCompletionEnabled="False" 
                         FilterMode="Contains" 
                         KeyUp="OmniSearch_KeyUp"
                         MouseLeftButtonUp="OmniSearch_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                         Margin="10,94,10,0" 
                         RenderTransformOrigin="0.518,1.92" Height="35"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

In code behind:

```
private void OmniSearch_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        BindingExpression exp = this.OmniSearchTextBox.GetBindingExpression(AutoCompleteBox.SelectedItemProperty);
        exp.UpdateSource();
    }
}

private void OmniSearch_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    BindingExpression exp = this.OmniSearchTextBox.GetBindingExpression(AutoCompleteBox.SelectedItemProperty);
    exp.UpdateSource();
}
```

In ViewModel:

```
private const string CompanyListPropertyName = "CompanyList";
private ObservableCollection<Company> _companyList;
public ObservableCollection<Company> CompanyList
{
    get
    {
        return _companyList;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_companyList == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _companyList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(CompanyListPropertyName);
    }

}

private Company _selectedObject;
public Company SelectedObject
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedObject;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedObject != value)
        {
            _selectedObject = value;
        }
    }
}
```